# REST API : breaking relationship if removed from JSON?

Tags: hibernate, rest, api, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I'm building an API using Spring Data JPA / hibernate / Spring Boot.
Let's say i have this JSON with this request : **GET /Parents/1**

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Dad",
"adoptedChildren": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Marie",
        "age": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Robert",
        "age": 9
    }
]
}
```

It's simply a Parent who have two adopted children.
Now for whatever reason this parent lost one child, so i receive this PUT request : PUT /Parents/1

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Dad",
"adoptedChildren": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Robert",
        "age": 9
    }
]
}
```

The JSON is missing one child.

I have two questions :

1. Is this the right way to allow breaking the link between Parent and Child ? **The child is not to be deleted**, i need just to break the relationship between the two ?
2. Should i rather allow the PUT operation only on the Child resource, to force the user to update the relationship from the Child side ?
3. If the solution **(1)** is ok, how do you do this update using Spring Data JPA ? When i update the entity with a missing child, it simply ignores it !

   ```
   @PutMapping("parents/{id}")
   public ItineraryDTO updateItinerary(@PathVariable int id, 
   @RequestBody Parent parent){
      return parentRepository.save(parent);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO it all depends from your model.

1) If your 'children' are dependent entities and don't have their own repository, then your choice is #1. But in this case you should correct your `Parent` class to make them properly work when you will save a parent entity with its nested children:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    //...
    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Child> children;
    //...
}
```

2) If your 'children' are independent objects and they have their own repo, then you should choose the second option - just remove a reference to the previous parent (set it to `null`) from the child entity while you are updating it:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    //...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private List<Child> children;
    //...
} 

@Entity
public class Child {
    //...
    @ManyToOne
    private Parent parent;
    //...
    public Child removeParent() {
         parent = null;
         return this;
    }
} 

@PutMapping("/childrent/{childId}/remove_parent")
public ResponseEntity removeParent(@PathVariable("childId") Long childId) {
    return childRepo.findById(childId)
        .map(c -> ResponseEntity.ok(childRepo.save(c.removeParent())))
        .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build())
}
```

P.S. It's just schematic model - in real project you should save entities in the service layer.